# How do i check programatically if an appender is started in log4j2 and start it if not started?

Tags: java, log4j2

I keep receiving the below error intermittently,

Attempted to append to non-started appender "XYZ" in a standalone program where i am creating the logger object programatically.

I am using

org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
and explicitely starting the appender before using it through 
appender.start();

Any Help appreciated.

Sample Code:

//Logger Class

public class LoggerDemo {

```
private Logger myLogger;  

public LoggerDemo(String fileName){
    LoggerContext context= (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    if (!context.hasLogger(fileName)) {
        Configuration config= context.getConfiguration();
        Layout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN, null, config, 
                null, null, false, false, null, null); 
        Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(fileName, "false", "false", "myLoggerFile", "true", 
                "false", "false", "40000", layout, null, "false", null, config);
        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);
        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", Level.ALL, fileName, "true", refs, null, config, null);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
        config.addLogger(fileName, loggerConfig);        
        context.updateLoggers();
    }
    processLogger = context.getLogger(fileName);
}
```

}

Main Class

```
public Class Test{
main(){
LoggerDemo logger = new LoggerDemo("abc.log");
//logger.info();
//and so on..
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some minimal code that shows what you're trying to do? Based on what you've said so far, it sounds like you might be trying to use log4j in a rather unsupported way.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to use programmatic configuration you should really consider using a configuration file instead. The reason is simple - by configuring log4j2 using java code you make your code dependent on the log4j2 implementation. If the implementation changes your code must also change. So I'd like to ask - why are you using programmatic configuration?

Comment: It is a part of requirement as i am creating the log files in separate threads.and each thread instantiation creates a new log file.

Comment: Is using the Same Appender name while creating multiple appenders  causing this issue?